# How to show multiple rows with MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
name|fileid|refferer|clicks|
good|same  |asda.com|20    |
good|same  |bsad.com|500   |
good|diffnt|csad.com|600   |
dddd|dasdds|asad.com|200   |
```

Output:

```
[asda.com,20],[bsda.com,500]
```

What I tried:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ios7_refclean`.`graph_refferer_table` WHERE Name = 'good'");
$rowz = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach ($rowz as $col => $value) {
  if (($col !== "fileid") && ($col !== "name")) {
  echo ",['" . $col . "'," . $value . "]";
}
```

However only one row of good is coming, the other rows are not coming. Also I am not able to link the `$col` of refferer with `$value` of clicks with square brackets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First of all, switch to MySQLi Or PDO because mysql_* functions were Deprecated.**

You need to use while loop for retrieving all rows:

```
 while($rowz = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  //your code here
 }
```

Also, you are using bad logic for printing your data, you can simply use:

```
 while($rowz = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $data[] = '['.$rowz['refferer'].','.$rowz['clicks'].']';
 }
echo implode(",", $data);
```